# Is there a way to get around using custom route key to load eloquent relationships in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models Product and Images. I changed the route key name on the product model to use the slug field and i'm now unable to load the hasMany relationship with the Image Model

Here is the Product Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected array $with = ['images'];

    public function getKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    protected array $guarded = [];


    public function images() : HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

and the Image model

```
class Image extends Model
{
    protected array $guarded = [];

    public function image() : BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

so when I try

```
    Product::first()->images
```

it just returns an empty collection
but without overriding the `getKeyName()` method, everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getKeyName()` will get the primary key for the model. it supports to return `id`, after you change it to `slug`, it will return `slug`

And `hasMany`[Here's the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L860) ;
The third parameter `LocalKey` will use `getKeyName()` when it's empty.

If you still want to use hasMany, you need to pass the third parameter like this:

```php
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

This will convert the Eloquent query to database query, which will take the right local key `products.id`.